# Consol error when children[1] is not present in the variable

Tags: javascript

My javascript code looks like this:

```
const xx = e.target.parentElement.children[1].children[1].innerHTML;   
imgText.innerHTML = xx;
```

It gets the `innerHTML` of a paragraphs of all cards within a div, and then insterting that into another paragraph somewhere else.

The thing is, that not every card has the last `children[1]` and it throws an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.target.parentElement.children[1].children[1] is undefined
```

Can I make it so it first checkes if the `xx` exists and then it would go to the second line of code?

I have tried using

```
if (x != null){}
   else{}
```

But it would throw the same error, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to make the whole expression return null if one element is null.

```
const xx = e.target?.parentElement?.children?.[1]?.children?.[1]?.innerHTML;

if (xx != null) {
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Element.childElementCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/childElementCount) to check if the element has the child and, if true, retreive it.

```js
const x = e.target.parentElement.children[1]
if(x.childElementCount > 0) {
    const xx = x.children[1].innerHTML
    // Use xx
}
```

Please use appropriate variable names.